# How does Mathematica handle a list of rule pairs when performing a substitution?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve linear second order differential equations using mathematica.

I have generated a list of rules, as in eq3rules in the below code.

When I perform the below substitution,

```
de3 /.eq3rules
```

**Will mathematica follow the pairs of assignment rules?** ie, y[x][[1]] will pair with y'[x][[1]],and y''[x][[1]]?

```
eq3 = y[x] == {E^x, Exp[2 x]}          
(* y[x] == {E^x, E^(2 x)} *)

Wronskian[eq3[[2]], x]        
(* E^(3 x) *)

(* W is non zero, so these are linearly independent *)


de3 = 0 == y''[x] - 3 y'[x] + 2*y[x]   
(* 0 == 2 y[x] - 3 Derivative[1][y][x] + y′′[x] *)

eq3rules = {eq3, D[eq3, x], D[eq3, {x, 2}]} /. Equal -> Rule       
(* {y[x] -> {E^x, E^(2 x)}, y'[x] -> {E^x, 2 E^(2 x)}, y''[x] -> {E^x, 4 E^(2 x)}} *)

de3 /. eq3rules     
(* 0 == {0, 0} *)
```

If it does not follow these rules, should I somehow group the rule sets for each solution into their own list elements?

So the new list would be

```
{{y_1[x],y_1'[x],y_1''[x]},{y_2[x],y_2'[x],y_2''[x]}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules of the type

```
{y[x] -> {E^x, E^(2 x)}
```

replace the full left-hand side with the right-hand side. In this case you replace a scalar with a vector. I have the impression that you actually would want replacement rules like

```
{y[x] -> E^x, y[x] -> E^(2 x)}
```

So, you need a way to split the first form into the second one (and the same for all derivatives). Something like `Distribute` will do that:

```
Distribute[#, List] & /@ eq3rules
(* {{y[x] -> E^x, y[x] -> E^(2 x)}, 
    {Derivative[1][y][x] -> E^x, Derivative[1][y][x] -> 2 E^(2 x)}, 
    {(y′′[x] -> E^x, y′′[x] -> 4 E^(2 x)}
   } *)
```

You now have 3 sets of 2 rules; one set for every derivative order. But since you want the rules for the various derivatives to be matched you need to add a `Transpose` to get 2 sets of 3 rules:

```
resRules=
Distribute[#, List] & /@ eq3rules // Transpose
(* {{y[x] -> E^x, Derivative[1][y][x] -> E^x, y′′[x] -> E^x}, 
    {y[x] -> E^(2 x), Derivative[1][y][x] -> 2 E^(2 x), y′′[x] ->4 E^(2 x)}} *)

de3 /. resRules
(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This, to me, is very idiomatic and elegant

Comment: You're welcome. A simple replacement like `eq3rules /. Rule[a_, {b_, c_}] -> {a -> b, a -> c}` instead of the `Distribute` would also do the trick.